# How to stop the status bar and navigation bar from animating along with screen transitions in Lollipop?

Tags: android, animation

I am making this app be compatible from 8-latest version. It works fine on lower version but when it is run on Lollipop the screen animation transitions have these black bars on top and below. Also, the fade out (i.e. using alpha) animations does not work smoothly. I tried searching but I can't seem to find an answer to what I am specifically facing.

I already have the `android:windowIsTranslucent` attribute in my theme and I can't change my theme to Theme.Tranluscent either.

How can I remove these bars? And why does my alpha animation not work on Lollipop?

Here is my Theme for the activity that I am trying to make look like a popup

```
<style name="ThemePopup" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/animationPop</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="animationPop">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/pop_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/fade_out</item>
</style>
```

Here is my fade out animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

<alpha
    android:duration="250"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />

</set>
```